# Why doesn't django's UpdateView just process POST data and instead displays a form?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

So I've been trying to put forms on the same index page for a list view and posting the data to another view to process it. It works fine for CreateView but not for UpdateView. Does anyone know how to make this work using class-based views?

Here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import *
from testapp.models import *
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
class list1(ListView):
    model = model1

class create(CreateView):
    model = model1
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

class update(UpdateView):
    model = model1
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

view1 = list1()
view2 = create()
view3 = update()

class index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['view1_object_list'] = view1.get_query_set()
        kwargs['cform'] = view2.get_form_class()
        kwargs['uform'] = view3.get_form_class()
        context = super(index, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

index.html

```
List1
<br>
{% for object in view1_object_list %}
  name: {{ object1.name }} description: {{ object1.description }} 
Edit: 
<form action="{% url 'update' pk=object.id %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ uform.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
{% endfor %}

Create item for list1:
<br>
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ cform.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testapp.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/$', index.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^create/$', create.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<pk>\d+)', update.as_view(), name='update'),
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: I think you do not undestant what Class-view are for.